# Narrowing search using multiple selects with ajax function

Tags: php, ajax

I have 3 selects that contain different categories. My website shows places to go out to eat and then I have one select that will let you choose between restaurants, bars... Another select will let you chose between a range of prices and the last one will let you chose the kind of atmosphere the place has.

The way I set it up is the following:

I have my 3 selects and a .click function that will pop when you chose something in any of the dropdowns:

```
$(".form_comer div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a, .form_salir div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a, .form_dormir div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a, .form_visitar div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").click(function(){

var index= $(this).attr('index');
var sel= ($(this).closest('div')).children('select').attr('id');
var value = $('select.jqTransformHidden option:eq('+index+')').attr('value');
       $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: $("#form").attr("action"),
     data: "value=" + value + "&sel=" + sel,
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data) {
        $("#cont-pag").html(data);
     }
     });
  return false; //prevent default browser action
});
```

It's a jqTransformed select, that makes the code harder. Value is the value of the selected item and sel is the id of the select clicked (price, for example)

This will call this php file where I do my query and paint my html that will show the places that fit the selected category (a bar, a 15€ place...) but it will only work for that category since I can't save the previous selection and I can't choose a place that fits 2 or 3 of the categories selected at the same time: First I choose to see al restaurants and then I click places that cost 40€ and when I do that I want it to still only show restaurants but I can't cange my variables through the ajax request.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch the values of all three select lists with `$(select#id).val()` and pass each of them along in your ajax call. You can then check which values aren't empty and append the ones that aren't to your query.

e.g.

```
$atmosphere = $_POST["atmosphere"];
if(!empty($atmosphere))
{
    $query .= " AND atmosphere = '$atmosphere'";
}
```

If the plugin prevents you from responding to clicks or changes this article may help you. [The jqTransform select problem and its solution](http://www.code-pal.com/the-select-problem-after-using-jqtransform-and-its-solution/).

If getting the values of the other select lists is a problem because the plugin doesn't allow for easy identification you could try looping over elements. I inspected the structure of a jqTransform form with firebug and noticed the selected value is always placed inside a  inside a  inside yet another with class="jqTransformSelectWrapper" so you could use jQuery's `.each()` in combination with `.find()` or something to get the `.text()` of the first span of the second div of each jqTransformSelectWrapper

Something along the lines of:

```
$('.jqTransformSelectWrapper').each(function(){$(this).find(div)[0].find(span)[0].text();});
```

Treat this as pseudo code, I'm not very experienced with jQuery

Comment: It's not that easy, I should have said earlier but I also have jqTransform applied to my selects and that makes them ul instead of selects. I had a lot of trouble getting the original id's of the selects for my actual script, I'm not sure how I can store the id's of the other 2 that are not selected in the moment of click. I will edit my post with all the code.

Comment: @Elaine Marley If you want to continue using this plugin to style your forms your only option may be to traverse the DOM of the document to manually get the innerText/texctContent value of the element that contains the selected option.

Comment: Ok, I get that. Another question I have is, once you pass the value of the selects to the ajax call, how do I retrieve them for the next call? Edit: nvm me, I just couldn't see the big picture. I was obsessed with just passing the selected value, not the three of them. Thank you.

Comment: Damn. I can't do it because the way I'm doing it I can only know what select I'm clicking because I'm clicking it. jqTransform doesn't apply id to the new transformed selects (and the hidden select doesn't show the selected option).

Comment: @Elaine Marley Perhaps this article can help you with an easy solution. [The jqTransform select problem and its solution](http://www.code-pal.com/the-select-problem-after-using-jqtransform-and-its-solution/). It describes how to get onchange event handlers to work on jqTransformed select lists and has an example on how to get the selected value.

Comment: That is exactly what I used for my click event, but I can't get the value for the other 2!

Comment: I understand your problem now. I inspected the structure of a jqTransform form with firebug and noticed the selected value is always placed inside a `<span>` inside a `<div>` inside yet another `<div>`with `class="jqTransformSelectWrapper"`so you could use jQuery's `.each()` or something to get the `.text()` of the first span of the second div of each jqTransformSelectWrapper

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering it would be something like that but I'm pretty much a noob with jquery. I'll try out your code, thank you very much. jqTransform is a bit of a pain in the ass.

Comment: @Elaine Marley As it turns out, `.each()` can't be used in the way I suggested. I'm not experienced enough with jQuery to come up with a proper statement to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you pass a value from each of the three fields each time you make a request to your PHP endpoint. Like this:

```
date: "type=" + $("#type_select").val() + "&price=" + $("#price_select").val() + "&atmosphere" = $("#atmosphere_select").val(),
```

Then have your PHP formulate a query that pulls only the relevant rows from the database.

This way you don't pull un-needed rows from the database if more than one filter is used, and don't need to do too much tinkering about with Javascript. I can imagine value=type&sel=restaurant could end up being quite a large result set in your current implementation.